# Sort array of elements by their ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to sort an array of DOM elements based on their ID. The array is populated by getting all elements with a given class:

```
var rowsList = document.getElementsByClassName("employee_grid_rows");
rowsList.sort(); //??
```

How do I get the sorting done by ID?

Comment: sort the array only ? or reposition the elements in the DOM in that order ?

Comment: I will reposition them, but I think I have that figured out

Comment: Are you using jQuery or not?

Comment: yes I'm using jQuery for some things, and vanilla for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to sort the HTMLCollection

```
var rowsList = document.getElementsByClassName("employee_grid_rows");
console.log(rowsList);

var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call( rowsList );
rowsList = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  //Comparing for strings instead of numbers
  return a.id.localeCompare(b.id);
});

console.log(rowsList);
```

Comment: you're declaring two "var rowsList" by the way

Comment: thanks, I kept getting 'undefined is not a function' when i tried to use sort, I think this fixed it!

Comment: question, I'm removing the divs and then re appending them with the new order, but they're coming back in the same order, my id's have "/" in them ("string/string/string") is this affecting the sorting?

Comment: I don't think so, post your code

Comment: The above solution would work for sorting numbers.  To sort on strings, use a.id.localeCompare(b.id);.  Solution is provided in my answer.

Comment: Yep, it only works for numbers, nice catch.

Comment: yea, I just tired Jeremy's suggestion, worked. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

```
rowList = rowList.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.id.localeCompare(b.id);
});
```

Comment: I don't have to do a.getAttribute('id')? a.id will work?

Comment: Yup, it's a DOM element property, and all specific elements inherit from the basic dom element, so they have the id property.

Comment: Does `HTMLCollection` object have `sort` method?

Comment: This answer is incorrect.

Comment: Since `id`s are always strings (they can't start with a number) this will not yield the expected result!

Comment: Thank-you.  I've made the required adjustment to compare for Strings.